# Associate and push an array into variable in object oriented PHP

Tags: php, arrays, oop, push

I'm trying to push an array into a variable in php7. My code is:

```
public $services = array(
    '01' => 'Canada Post - Priority',
    '02' => 'Canada Post - Regular Parcel',
    '03' => 'Canada Post - Xpresspost',
    '04' => 'Purolator Express 9AM',
    '05' => 'Purolator Express 1030AM',
    '06' => 'Purolator Express',
    '07' => 'Purolator Ground',
);
```

Instead of the harded code part I wish to push my array that I've obtain in this way

```
public function easypost_database()
    {

        \EasyPost\EasyPost::setApiKey('mykey');
        $cas = \EasyPost\CarrierAccount::all();
        $carriers = array();
        foreach($cas as $key=>$value) {
            $carriers[] = $value['type'];

       }

       return $carriers;
   }
```

My array $carriers looks like that;

```
Array ( [0] => CanadaPostAccount 
[1] => PurolatorAccount )
```

The problem is that when I associate my variable with my array my code breaks.

```
public $services = $carriers;
```

and

```
public $services = $this->easypost_database();
```

won't work.

Comment: You cannot init class property in such way. Why not use `$this->services` in your function?

Comment: So, instead of $carriers[]  = = $value['type']; I should use $this->service = = $value['type'];  and then declare my variable services as public $services; ?

Comment: And why can't I do the opposite?

Comment: `$this->service[] = $value['type']`, yes. By opposite you mean what?

Comment: return $carriers to use it somewhere else

Comment: You can return carriers. You __cannot define property__ with a dynamic value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing wont work, and it is basically poorly designed.

If you need to use  `$carriers` inside the class where you define `easypost_database()`, you should probably inject this dependency when creating this object.

You'd have:

```
class MyClass {

   protected $services;

   public function __construct(array $services) {
     $this->services = $services;
   }
}
```

Without knowing more about your system it's not possible to guess how are you resolving your dependencies or if you are using any type of container or service locator. But putting it simply, to instantiate this object you'd need to do something like:

```
\EasyPost\EasyPost::setApiKey('mykey');
$cas = \EasyPost\CarrierAccount::all();
$carriers = [];
foreach($cas as $key=>$value) {
    $carriers[] = $value['type'];
}

$foo = new MyClass($carriers);
```

And now you'd be able to access `$this->services` from within your class.

But properties definition need to be able to be resolved at compile time, so the kind of expression you want to use would never work.

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.